# Как сделать синхронные запросы?

Tags: java, android

Не могу разобрать, как сделать синхронные запросы внутри одного треда, чтобы не блокировать такие же синхронные запросы внутри других тредов.

для примера, хочу получить следующее:

```
for (Obj obj: objects) {
       Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
       @Override
       public void run() {
       try {
          res = hDownloadUrl(obj.url, null);
           // делаем некоторую работу, где так же посылаем запросы, поэтому и получается, что нужны синхронные запросы внутри треда
       } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
       }
       }
    });
    t.start();
}
```

где `hDownloadUrl` это:

```
   public InputStream hDownloadUrl(String urlString, String userAgent) throws IOException {
        Log.w("Helper hDownloadUrl: ", urlString);
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        if (userAgent != null){
            conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", userAgent);
        }
        conn.connect();
        return conn.getInputStream();
    }
```

Колбеки `volley` я не знаю, как тут использовать.

Comment: Т.е. вы загружаете некий список ссылок или html-страницу, и хотите загружать данные по этим ссылкам параллельно? Мне кажется, для этого достаточно просто из `onResponse` в Volley добавлять новые запросы в ту же очередь, и дальше, если очередь настроена на несколько потоков, то запросы будут обработаны параллельно. Ну или сделать то же самое руками через `java.util.concurrent.Executor` и `Runnable`.

Comment: **если очередь настроена на несколько потоков** разве это по умолчанию не так?

Comment: По-умолчанию там `RequestQueue.DEFAULT_NETWORK_THREAD_POOL_SIZE = 4`. Проблема с Volley в том, что закачка производится в своем потоке, а callback-и вызываются в одном ui-thread. Можно передать в конструктор `RequestQueue` свой `new ExecutorDelivery(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4) )`, или сделать свою реализацию `ResponseDelivery`.

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте в метод **hDownloadUrl()** ключевое слово **synchronized**

```
synchronized public InputStream hDownloadUrl(String urlString, String userAgent) throws IOException {
        Log.w("Helper hDownloadUrl: ", urlString);
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        if (userAgent != null){
            conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", userAgent);
        }
        conn.connect();
        return conn.getInputStream();
    }
```

Также необходимо сделать не просто одну глобальную переменную, которая хранит ответ, а **ArrayList array**, в которую вы будете добавлять все ответы от сервера вот так:

```
array.add(hDownloadUrl(obj.url, null));
```

вместо

```
res = hDownloadUrl(obj.url, null);
```

Comment: спасибо, но вы, наверное, не поняли мою проблему, synchronized насколько я знаю наобот гарантирует выполнение только кода только одним потоком, а мне нужно что бы наоборот, одновременны в разных потоках выполнялись запросы

Comment: Не, вы неправильно поняли, если они будут synchronized, то они будут в разных потоках выполняться, просто добавление информации в переменную **array** будет выполняться одни потоком, который успел раньше всех и т.д., но все остальные операции будут выполняться синхронно.

Comment: @Tany Кстати, почитайте более подробно про многопоточность, с ней не всё так, как вы себе представляете. На самом деле всё выполняется последовательно, просто пока один поток чего-то ждёт другие потоки в этот момент могут работать. Настоящая многопоточность может быть реализована на многоядерности процессора и больше чем количество ядер(включая виртуальные ядра) потоков РЕАЛЬНО одновременно работать не будет.

Comment: Можете добавить не такую строчку **array.add(hDownloadUrl(obj.url, null));**, а две таких **InputStream result = hDownloadUrl(obj.url, null);**  **array.add(result);** Я думаю, что так даже правильнее будет

Comment: да, я не подумал об этом, тоесть получаеться что я тестирую на nexus 7 2012 года, у него вроде как 1 ядро, то в итоге получаеться что все работает практически линейно, иногда просто потоки переключаеються между собой?

Comment: хотя нет - Количество ядер 4+1

Comment: Да, именно так. Почитайте статью про многопоточность, регистры прерывания и стек команд